# need to access current TR or TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to change the table row color based on some business logic. I have limited access. 
I have PHP code which decide TD content...from that TD I have to change the current TR background color.

jQuery can help, as it is having lot of traverser and accesser.

code I am writing is

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(this).closest("td").css("border", "1px solid red");</script>
```

But not able to access the current TD or TR

Comment: What event are you attaching the change to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can use parents() funciton.

if your element is $('#el') then following will give you nearest td and tr

```
$('#el').parents('td').first();
$('#el').parents('tr').first();
```

then you can apply operation like below

```
$('#el').parents('td').first().css("border", "1px solid red");
$('#el').parents('tr').first().css("border", "1px solid red");
```

Comment: I cant give ID or name to element so I have to use {this} intstead of {#el}

Comment: .closest() is much better than .parents() - there's some performance gain

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **this**, give the element an id and get it using jQuery. In your code, this points to nothing. like:

```
<table><tr><td> <input id="myInput" type="text" /> </td></tr></table>

 //If you want to access the td
 $('#myInput').closest("td").css("border", "1px solid red");
 //If you want to access the tr
 $('#myInput').closest("tr").css("background", "red");
```

Comment: This won't do anything with TR background color, it will just add border to one of TDs. What he needs: `from that TD I have to change the current TR background color`.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to target the TD content or the TD itself. If the content was unique you could search for a keyword or phrase. Either way, you need a selector - $(this) is just a reference to the jquery object once inside a handler.

**EDIT**

I thought about it a bit more and here's something you could try. Since you only have access to the content, could you add something to it like *UPDATED*? If so, then you could add that keyword and with jQuery we can add in the border, background and remove the keyword like this:

```
​<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" border="1px">
    <tr><td>*UPDATED*Apple</td><td>Pie</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Orange</td><td>Crush</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

-

```
var $updatedContent = $('td:contains("*UPDATED*")');

$updatedContent.closest('td').css('border', '1px solid red').closest('tr').css('background','green');
$updatedContent.text($updatedContent.text().replace('*UPDATED*', ''));
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the worst case, where you have nested tables and you cannot change current TD attributes, than print an empty span within it this way:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Content 1
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 2<span data-class="very_important" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Than add class to (first or last) parent TR like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('span[data-class]').each(function(n) {
        var highlightClass = $(this).attr('data-class');
        $(this).parents('tr:first').addClass( highlightClass );
        $(this).remove(); /* Optional */
    });
});
```

Now your TR has class and you can style it (and its children) the way you like. Result code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Content 1
        <table>
        <tr class="very_important">
            <td>Content 2</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```